# How to catch unsupported css properties during webpack build

Tags: css, webpack, less, webpack-2

Let's say the app I am working supports a set of browsers, there are chances that the CSS property I used might not work in one of the supported browser. How to catch such CSS properties during webpack build given a set of browser matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a CSS lint loader. For example:

https://github.com/hyungjs/csslint-loader

I'm not saying use this specific one as I don't have any experience with it but this should set you in the right direction.